# Using the toInteger function with locale and format parameters

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've got a dataflow with a csv file as source. The column NewPositive is a string and it contains numbers formatted in European style with a dot as thousand seperator e.g 1.019 meaning 1019

If I use the function toInteger to convert my NewPositive column to an int via toInteger(NewPositive,'#.###','de'), I only get the thousand cipher e.g 1 for 1.019 and not the rest. Why? For testing I tried creating a constant column: toInteger('1.019','#.###','de') and it gives 1019 as expected. So why does the function not work for my column? The column is trimmed and if I compare the first value with equality function: equals('1.019',NewPositive) returns true.

**Please note**: I know it's very easy to **create a workaround** by toInteger(replace(NewPositive,'.','')), but I want to learn how to use the toInteger function with the locale and format parameters.

Here is sample data:

Dato;NewPositive
2021-08-20;1.234
2021-08-21;1.789

Answer (score 1):

I was able to repro this and probably looks to be a bug to me . I have reported this to the ADF team , will let you know once I hear back from them . You already have a work around please go ahead that to unblock yourself .